# How can i split a string in an ArrayList in JAVA

Tags: java

How can i split a String into an ArrayList in java? 
I am reading the String

```
st = input.nextLine();
```

and i want to split it in my ArrayList

```
list.add(st);
```

Comment: what's your delimiter to split your string ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a String in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Call split, iterate over the result and add it to your list (or directly convert the String[] to ArrayList)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `comma(,)` is your delimiter, you can do this with

```
new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList( str.split(",") ));
```

Answer (score 1):

First Way:

```
String str = "test,abc,123,xyz,win,hk";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));
System.out.println(list);
```

Second Way:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
  for(int win = 0; win < str.split(",").length; win++ ){
    list1.add(str.split(",")[win]);
  }
System.out.println(list1);
```